# How can I use ActiveRecord::Observer in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sinatra

I'm successfully using ActiveRecord 3.2.9 in a Sinatra 1.3.3 application.  I would like to be able to use ActiveRecord::Observer classes, but I'm not sure how to activate them.

The ActiveRecord::Observer [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html) are specific to Rails about this particular bit:

> In order to activate an observer, list it in the config.active_record.observers configuration setting in your config/application.rb file.

Of course, I don't have a "config" object on which to set this setting.  Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I tried activating the observers like so:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.observers = [ :thermometer_reading_observer ]
```

This does something, in that they are correctly set, but they still don't do anything:

```
[4] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.observers
=> [:thermometer_reading_observer]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it figured out from perusing the ActiveRecord source [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/observer.rb):

To activate an observer outside of Rails, do the following (with my Observer as an example):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.add_observer ThermometerReadingObserver.instance
```

Hopefully this helps someone!